# Particle system "shoot at an object"

Tags: particles, physics

Thank you for your time reader!

I want a particle system to shoot (laz0rs) at an object (in this scenario a plane / ground).

So far I learned that keyed physics is the way to go.
I got three Objects now:

1. Ground / target plane (particle system with no physics)
2. Shooter cube / emitter (same particle system)
3. Helper cube / (particle system with keyed physics)

**But I cant manage to rotate particles toward the "target"**

Does someone have an advice for me? :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the rotation tool in the particle system. Set this to 'Velocity / Hair'. This way, the particles will always face the direction they are going.
[image]
[image]

Comment: "display"->"point" (+velocity checkbox) looks nice
but with "render"->"object" it looks like this
[link](https://ibb.co/fuYwga)

Comment: WORKED - i had to turn on "dynamic" checkbox (dont exactly know why) - looks like this now: [link](https://ibb.co/eV9cMa)

Comment: Have again to correct myself:
It still does not work with the two particle systems with one being keyed physics (the velocity arrows look nice there too but the objects are not rotated)

Answer (score 1):

To force particles (missiles) to 'point at' their target enroute, simply place a  'Track to'  Constraint  on the particle object from which they are fashioned.

[image]     [image]

Place the Particle-Object fairly close to the emitter so it will align the particles properly to the target.

When it's all looking ok, this object can be moved to another layer that won't be rendered.
 (it will however continue to control particle direction)

If you don't want particles that are emitted early, having to reverse course, (anim 1) delay the emiiter's starting frame to one where the object is aligned reasonably to the final trajectory. (anim 2)

EDIT: 18th / Aug / 2017

Forgot to mention, it will be necessary to tick the "Rotation" box in the emitter's 'Render' tab.

[image]

Comment: Almost a solution but the rotation towards velocity is missing (and if I turn it on it gets messed up) - without it looks like this: [link](https://ibb.co/nFovU5)